# Selecting a subset using dropna() to select multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,3],[10,20,2,],[10,2,5,],[1,3],[2]],columns = ['a','b','c','d'])
```

From this DataFrame, I want to drop the rows where all values in the subset ['b', 'c', 'd'] are NA, which means the last row should be dropped.

The following code works:

```
df.dropna(subset=['b', 'c', 'd'], how = 'all')
```

However, considering that I will be working with larger data frames, I would like to select the same subset using the range  ['b':'d']. How do I select this subset?

Comment: @ayhan yes, something like that, except I realised `:` might result in an expensive copy :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah I was looking into `columns.slice_locs` to avoid that but yours is a nice hack. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IIUC, use `loc`, retrieve those columns, and pass that to `dropna`.

```
c = df.loc[0, 'b':'d'].columns  # retrieve only the 0th row for efficiency
df = df.dropna(subset=c, how='all')

print(df) 
    a     b    c    d
0   1   2.0  3.0  3.0
1  10  20.0  2.0  NaN
2  10   2.0  5.0  NaN
3   1   3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: it's an interesting hack ;-)

Comment: There's a colon missing, otherwise you'll get a series which doesn't have columns: c = df.loc[:0, 'b':'d'].columns

Answer (score 5):

You could also slice the column list numerically:

```
c = df.columns[1:4]  
df = df.dropna(subset=c, how='all')
```

If using numbers is impractical (i.e. too many to count), there is a somewhat cumbersome work-around:

```
start, stop = df.columns.get_loc('b'), df.columns.get_loc('d')
c = df.columns[start:stop+1]
df = df.dropna(subset=c, how='all')
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [@ayhan's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285236/ayhan) - using [df.columns.slice_indexer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.slice_indexer.html):

```
In [25]: cols = df.columns[df.columns.slice_indexer('b','d')]

In [26]: cols
Out[26]: Index(['b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')

In [27]: df.dropna(subset=cols, how='all')
Out[27]:
    a     b    c    d
0   1   2.0  3.0  3.0
1  10  20.0  2.0  NaN
2  10   2.0  5.0  NaN
3   1   3.0  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Argh, I'm out of votes for today, downvoting all the horrible questions out there.  >:-( I'll go undo some for this!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, don't let the dark side of Power to control you :-D