# Pandas: Drop row if second column is blank

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use Python3 and Pandas to shape a dataframe.

My current frame looks like this:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-baqh"></th>
    <th class="tg-baqh">Col1</th>
    <th class="tg-baqh">Col2</th>
    <th class="tg-baqh">Col3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">0</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">X</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Y</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh">1</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh"></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">Z</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to drop the row if the second column is blank (so drop row 2, index 1, only here), but the name of the second column can change depending on the file being used so Im attempting to use ix but to no avail...

```
c = df.ix[:,1]
df.dropna(subset=c, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Any advice?

Comment: I'm confused, how is the second column blank for row 2?

Comment: Look at coldspeed's previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46864740/selecting-a-subset-using-dropna-to-select-multiple-columns. It's awesome!  Combine dropNa and subset.

Comment: Documentation for subset gives - "subset : array-like
    Labels along other axis to consider, e.g. if you are dropping rows
    these would be a list of columns to include". Simply, `df.dropna(subset=['Col2'], how='all', inplace=True)`

Comment: @anonyXmous Aww, thank you :)

Comment: @coldspeed: Sorry I'm counting the top row as Row 0 just to confuse things. Index number 1 is the row I need to drop.

Comment: @Mayur H: Subset works fine but I don't know the column name, how can I do this without knowing the name of the column? I can get it to work fine when I know the columns name using Subset.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question. You can get the columns names and store it to a variable with:

```
x= df.columns.tolist()[0]
```

then:

```
df=df[df[x].isnull()==False]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
second = df[df.columns.tolist()[1]]
df = df[second.notnull()]
```